# Mapping screen coordinate to Node coordinate in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I need to map a screen coordinate (retrieved from an eyetracker) to a Node coordinate (ImageView). Is there a way to do this with JavaFX?

Comment: Did you search the documentation? [Node#screenToLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#screenToLocal-double-double-) seems to do what you describe.

Comment: Oh boy, i googled for about 15 minutes. How dows "javafx screen to local" not show this? Thank you anyways!

Comment: Instead of using google, why not just read the actual documentation?

Comment: JavaFX is very confusing in the beginning, i don't know where to search for specific stuff. Besides that the docs are pretty big, why wouldn't i use google?

Comment: > why wouldn't i use google? Maybe because you do not always find what you are looking for :-)